# Scala type parameters in various places

Tags: scala, oop, types, functional-programming

I have just started learning scala and have some issues with general understanding of type parameters. Previously I learned Haskell, but in scala it seems very confusing to me. It is unclear for me where should I put type parameters (near class definition or function definition).

Consider the example:

```
class Person[A] {
  def sayName (name: A) = println(name)
}
```

Does it make sense to move type parameter from class to function?

```
class Person {
  def sayName[A] (name: A) = println(name)
}
```

Or I even can leave type parameter both in class and function and it will work. Does it make some big difference? 
Will the [A] parameters in function override same param from class definition?

And I can create the instance of Person or call a function without pointing the exact type.

```
val p = new Person();
```

So why is this for? Just in cases when I want smth generic? 
So it is unclear for me when and on which positions (class or function) should I put type parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- If you declare the type parameter at the *class* level, you assign the actual type upon **construction**, and can't change it later - all invocations of `sayName` on a given instance will have to use the same type.
- If you declare the type parameter at the *method* level, you can assign a different type in each **invocation** of the method.

So - if an instance of the class should always apply to a single type - use class-level definition.

For example:

```
trait Animal
case class Dog() extends Animal
case class Cat() extends Animal

// A single owner has a *specific* pet, 
// so it makes sense to declare type at class level
class Owner[A <: Animal] {
  def feed(a: A) = ???
}

// A single RandomAnimalLover walking down the street, 
// might feed both Dogs and Cats - so their feed method must be parameterized, and there's no use in adding a parameter at the class level
class RandomAnimalLover {
  def feed[A <: Animal](a: A) = ???
}

val dog = Dog()
val cat = Cat()
val ownerA = new Owner[Dog]
val randomDude = new RandomAnimalLover

ownerA.feed(dog) // compiles
ownerA.feed(cat) // does not compile

randomDude.feed(dog) // compiles
randomDude.feed(cat) // compiles
```

Lastly, if you declare a type parameter **both** at the class level and at the method level - these are two separate parameters!

- If they have different names, both can be used anywhere.
- If they have the same name, the method-level parameter will **shadow** the class level parameter within the scope of that method's definition and implementation (but nowhere else in the class).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve will dictate where to put the type parameter.

### Type parameter in class definition

Put the type parameter in the class definition to make some attribute of your class generic. It could be a `val`, a class parameter or a function argument.

### Type parameter in method definition

Put the type parameter in the class definition to allow your method to be called with a generic type.

### Example

```scala
class Person[A](name: A) {
  def sayName = println(name)
  def sayFirstName(firstName: A) = println(firstName)
  def saySomething[B](thing: B) = println(s"$name says $thing")
}

// in console

scala> val p = new Person[String]("Barker")
p: Person[String] = Person@4f5a80a8

scala> p.sayName
Barker

scala> p.sayFirstName("John")
John

scala> p.sayFirstName(4)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(4)
 required: String
   p.sayFirstName(4)
                  ^

scala> p.saySomething("hello")
Barker says hello

scala> p.saySomething(42)
Barker says 42
```

Method `sayFirstName` takes an argument the same type as `name`. I want `name` and `firstName` to have the same type, and I can enforce it this way.

Method `saySomething` has a new type parameter `B`. So the `Person` can say something of any type.

### Side note

As you noted, you could also replace `B` by `A` and have the same behavior: the type argument in the method definition will override the one in the class definition. But this should be avoided for the sake of readability.